# How to set UITextField's correct tag in a loop

Tags: objective-c

I have a loop that generates 100 textfields 10x10.

```
int counter=0;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
{
    for (int ii = 0; ii < 10; ii++) 
    {
        counter++;
        UITextField *tf = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0 + 25 * i ,60+25*ii,25,25)];
        counter++;
        tf.tag =counter;

        [self.view addSubview:tf];
    }
}
```

- The above code will create all the 100 textfield but with tags assigned very badly and in an incorrect order.

**This is what I get:**

1.Tags representation

```
1 11 21 31 41 51 61 71 81 91
2 12 22 32 42 52 62 72 82 92
3 …………
```

2.This is what I want:

```
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
21………..
```

Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: `[tf setTag:(i*10+ii+1)];`?

Comment: @Larmen nope, same result.

Comment: `[tf setTag:(ii*10+i+1)];`? I mixed `i` && `ii`. You should rename them i:column and ii:line.

Comment: [tf setTag:(ii*10+i+1)]; did the trick! correct anwser! post it so i can accept it! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, forget about `counter`. You can retrieve it with you `i` and `ii`.

Let's see what your 2 `for` loop do, where a "-" mean nothing yet, and a "•" a `UITextField` is put.

```
----------
----------
----------
```

Then:

```
•---------
----------
----------
```

Then:

```
•---------
•---------
----------
```

etc.

So we quickly see that `i` represents a column and `ii` a line. It would be good to rename them like this.
Now, if you had logged `i` and `ii` you could have figured out what was the logic, which is:

```
[tf setTag:(ii*10+i+1)];
```

Note that's just a kindly advice (not a "you could have done it alone if you did the debug yourself") to log things sometimes (like the counter: `i` or `ii` in our case) to understand them, especially in loops, when it can get tricky. I do that often when my loops don't do what I expect.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    for (int ii = 0; ii < 10; ii++)
    {
        UITextField *tf = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0 + 25 * ii,60+25*i, 25, 25)];
        tf.tag = ii + i * 10 + 1;
        [self.view addSubview:tf];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility:

```
int row = 0;
int column = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
   if (!(i % 10) && i) {
      row++;
      column = 0;
   }
   CGRect newRect = CGRectMake(25.0 * column, 60.0 + 25.0 * row, 25.0, 25.0);
   UITextField *tf = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:newRect];

   tf.tag = i;
   [self.view addSubview:tf];

   column++;
}
```